# My Nexus 7 isn't being detected by Windows. No OS on Nexus 7

Tags: adb, nexus-7, rom, usb-drivers

I wiped my OS from my Nexus earlier as I had a ROM that I wanted to flash. When I proceeded to try and flash the ROM to my Nexus 7 using flash-all.bat (I installed ADB and Fastboot and Drivers using 15 second installer by Snoop05) it hung on: < Waiting for device >. I've been able to track it down to the drivers since there is an error on my device manager. I have tried numerous tutorials and methods to get the drivers but they all seem to need you to have your device already running android. I have TWRP recovery and unlocked bootloader. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried using one of the driver install tutorials with the device attached in fastboot mode?

Comment: Could you link me to some I cannot find any googling around

Comment: You've implied that you've got a tutorial.
"I have tried numerous tutorials and methods to get the drivers but they all seem to need you to have your device already running android."
Try one of those with the device attached in fastboot mode.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is something quite strange although seemed to work for me. I used a different computer and used Wugs Nexus Root Toolkit to flash stock (after driver install on other computer) and it worked without any failure .